# heroku - clone - Operation timed out

Tags: git, heroku

I am using MacOs Lion.
I installed the heroku CLI.
I was able to successfully login: `heroku login`

I created a node.js app and got the git repo url. However when I run:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:potrerosanluis.git -o heroku
Cloning into potrerosanluis...
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I then ran: `heroku keys:add` thinking it could be some problem with the ssh key. However problem still persists.

I am new to heroku, git. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't want to be using Heroku as your Git repo and cloning from it.  It's far better to use something like Github.

Comment: @NeilMiddleton but if it's a project and he joined in?

Comment: Still stands.  Ideally you should not be using Heroku as your primary source control partner.

Comment: @NeilMiddleton was just following the heroku facebook tutorial: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook.
I would prefer the repo to be hosted on bitbucket. First time using git, so I am in the dark as to how to achieve this. Tips?

Comment: @NeilMiddleton getting more comfortable with git now. I followed your suggestion and have set up bitbucket to be the primary repo.
git remote add bitbucket the_url
git push bitbucket master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work.
I had not generated the ssh-key when I first logged in.
Just followed the steps [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) to create and register a new ssh-key and it worked.